# copy UIImageView that pulls from setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview

before i had been pulling the same image twice from my server by using, which worked fine but i need to cut down network usage

```
NSString *friendAvatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://www.mydomain.com/images/users/", myWords[0], @".jpg"];
[imageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
[bgImageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]]; //this is a zoomed in version of the friends photo
```

now i am using this way to attempt to pul the image of the UIImageView that already pulled the photo, that way i dont have to be pulling the same photo twice...

```
NSString *friendAvatar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://www.mydomain.com/images/users/", myWords[0], @".jpg"];
[imageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];
[bgImageFile setImage:imageFile.image];
```

when trying to use my new method. nothing happens. no error in the debugger, the background image just simply is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a UIImage first then set UIImageView.image to the created UIImage...

```
UIImage *avatarImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]]];

[imageFile setImage:avatarImage];
[bgImageFile setImage:avatarImage];
```

And a better way would be...

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myProgram.myQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    UIImage *avatarImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imageFile setImage:avatarImage];
        [bgImageFile setImage:avatarImage];
    });
});
```

This will load the file from the internet on a background thread and then update the ImageViews on the main thread when the image is done loading.  The benefit is that your app won't freeze up during downloading.

I hope that helps

Comment: My app already multi threads and takes care of handling server info in the background thread, i use AFNetworking . So is your second example still necessary for me? I'll give the first one a shot

Comment: im getting `No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'imageWithData:'`

Comment: I am sorry it is – initWithData:

Comment: i changed it to `UIImage *avatarImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]]];` and now it freezes the ui really bad, i also used your second myQueue method and still same result, slow UI... really... really slow lol. But it does work

Comment: Damn...I think that they are both equally slow because of the loading, the only difference is that the first actually freezes user interaction during the download and the second does not.  Is there a delay in the image loading in your original code?

Comment: using initwithData is not the correct solution even when using it in blocks. That is the reason people prefer AFNetworking - setImage withPlaceholder. But in AFNetworking, you can have a placeholder image, but the image loading time is still the same

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I discovered that because you are using `AFNetworking` when you call

`[imageFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendAvatar]];`

it is being executed on a background thread, but the next line

```
[bgImageFile setImage:imageFile.image];
```

is not a AFNetworking call so it is being executed before the previous line has completed and thus there is no imageFile.image to use...

So, yes, my previous answer requires you to do the async code yourself, or you could wait for the image to load before setting bgImageFile.image (Which might be done with KVO???)